# Dropdown not working inside clickable parent div

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, dropdown

I am able to open bootstrap dropdown. Please help me. I have added the stackblitz link.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-base-cards-gvhfuz

Comment: Of course it will not work because you are trying to use the jquery $ but you need to declare and import it.

Comment: I have removed jquery.  I was just trying if could be solved using jquery. Can you give solution without jquery or with jquery ?

Comment: Here is the official link of the dropdown bootstrap.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/
Just be sure you implement the same and it will do the job.

Comment: Can you implement it in stackbitz ?